# Isotope not working/applying classes to divs generated by Knockout 'foreach'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, jquery-isotope

I have the following html:

```
<h2 class="groupHeader" id="succeededHeader"></h2>
    <div id="container" data-bind="foreach: successfulProjects">
        <div class="element">
            <div data-bind="attr: { 'class': StatusClass }">
                <h3 class="projectItemTitle" data-bind="text: ProjectName"></h3>
                <h2 class="buildConfigName" data-bind="text: BuildConfigName"></h2>
                <p>
                    Last build Time:<br />
                    <span class="lastBuildTime" data-bind="text: LastBuildTime"></span>
                </p>
                <p>Tests Passed:</p>
                <p>Tests Failed:</p>
            </div>
            </>
        </div>
```

And the following JS:

```
$(function () {
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.element'
        });

        var $select = $('#filters select');

        $select.change(function () {
            var filters = $(this).val();
            console.log(filters);
            $container.isotope({
                filter: filters
            });
        });

    });
```

When the html is generated with the Knockout foreach, it comes out:

```
<div id="container" class="isotope" data-bind="foreach: successfulProjects" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 0px;">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
<div class="element">
</div>
```

There are no isotope classes applied to the items within and no form of sorting or filtering works. Do these libraries actually mix? Does isotope work with elements that are generated in this way?

Any help/suggestions would be gratefully received.

Christian

Comment: When do you call `ko.applyBindings()` ? Because if you call it before the `$container.isotope({` call then it should work fine....